# How to add a Validation such that only one of the 2 fields has to be filled in Aura component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation

I tried following the tutorial here https://www.sfdcstop.com/2018/03/salesforce-lightning-tutorial-part-5.html but got stuck as below.

***a.cmp***

```
...
<td>
    <lightning:input aura:id="formFieldToValidate"
                     messageWhenValueMissing="Either Nationality ID Number OR Passport Number is to be filled" 
                     name="nationalid" 
                     value="{!item.nth.National_ID_Number__c}"/>
</td>
<td>
     <lightning:input aura:id="formFieldToValidate" 
                      messageWhenValueMissing="Either Nationality ID Number OR Passport Number is to be filled" 
                      name="passportnumber" 
                      value="{!item.nth.Passport_Number__c}"/>
</td>
...
```

***aController.js***

```
({
  validate : function(component,event){

    // Getting all fields and iterate them to check for validity
    var allValid = component.find('formFieldToValidate').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
        // Show help message if single field is invalid
        inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        // Get the name of each field
        var name = inputCmp.get('v.name');
        var passportValue;
        var nationalIdValue;

        if(name=='nationalid') {
            nationalIdValue = inputCmp.get('v.value');
        }
        if(name=='passportnumber') {
            passportValue = inputCmp.get('v.value');
        }

        if(nationalIdValue == '' && passportValue == '') {
            // Focus on that field to make custom validation work
            inputCmp.focus();
            // Setting the custom validation
            inputCmp.set('v.validity', {valid:false, badInput :true});
        }                

        // Returning the final result of validations
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
    }, true);
    // Returning Validate contact result in boolean
    return allValid;
}
```

When I tried not filling both fields and then click "Save", nothing happens and no error message is prompted. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will throw an error when both of the fields are null or when both of the fields have the value, it will only proceed if one of the fields have value.

component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="v1" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="v2" type="String"/>
    <td>
        <lightning:input aura:id="formFieldToValidate"

                         name="nationalid" 
                         value="{!v.v1}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <lightning:input aura:id="formFieldToValidate" 

                         name="passportnumber" 
                         value="{!v.v2}"/>
    </td>
    <lightning:button label="validate" onclick="{!c.validateIt}" />
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({
    validateIt : function(component, event, helper) {

        var v1 = component.get("v.v1");
        var v2 = component.get("v.v2");

        if((!v1  && !v2) || (v1 && v2)  ) {
            alert('Either Nationality ID Number OR Passport Number is to be filled');
        }

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a **required** attribute in the **lightning:input** tag. 'messagewhenvaluemissing' only works when the input is required. Also, u can make a input required conditionally.